# how to use "if" to test the presence of an element in the webpage with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a loop `(while True)` to automate a task on the site with python. This code clicks on two fields until an element appears on the page

`(browser.find_element_by_id ('formComp: buttonBack')`.

When this element appears, I want the loop to stop and go to the next block of code.

I tested it that way, but it made a mistake. Python reported that the element `"formComp: buttonback"` was not found. But that's just it, if not found continue the loop:

```
    while (browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:repeatCompromissoLista:0:tableRealizacao:0:subtableVinculacoes:0:vinculacao_input')):
        vinc = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'formComp:repeatCompromissoLista:0:tableRealizacao:0:subtableVinculacoes:0:vinculacao_input')))
        vinc = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:repeatCompromissoLista:0:tableRealizacao:0:subtableVinculacoes:0:vinculacao_input')
        vinc.send_keys('400')
        enterElem5 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'formComp:buttonConfirmar')))
        enterElem5 = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:buttonConfirmar')
        enterElem5.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(int(segundosv))
        if (browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:buttonRetornar')== True):
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: We need more information. What error happened when you ran which code? I don't see the `while True:` you mentioned, so is the code you showed the one with the problem or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this hope this helps.Check the `length` count of the button more than 0.

```
if (len(browser.find_elements_by_id('formComp:buttonRetornar'))>0):
        break
else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_id()` does not return `False` when an element is not found.  Instead, it raises `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`.  You can handle the exception to get the flow control you are looking for:

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:buttonRetornar')
    break
except NoSuchElementException:
    continue
```